# Spiral galaxy stability

Tags: astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, stability

Is there a limit of baryonic masses $M_{B}$ ($M_{B}=M_{\star}+M_{g}$), beyond which a spiral galaxy is no longer rotationally supported? Like for example: Could spiral galaxies of baryonic masses $M_{B}>10^{12} M_{\odot}$ be stable? Why?